# Android checkbox unexpectedly Checked within a Listview

Tags: android, listview, view, checkbox, android-arrayadapter

In my android application I have used pagination to show all of my product using a listview. Inside listview there are one checkBox and one imageview. I am using checkBox to select the particular image from listview. I am getting all image from server. Firstly I am taking all image inside an ArryList and then I am taking 5 elements inside android temporary ArrayList and using that temporary for the Custom Array Adapter and loading that 5 image. The problem is when I am selecting one checkbox to select particular image and clicking next button then inside new page I am getting another checkBox that is selected. Beside this I am getting one selected button inside every page. How to remove this? I want that checkbox in Checked where I have Clicked. My code is given below .

```
private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<WatchListAllEntity> {

    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM_WITH_HEADER = 1;
    private ArrayList<WatchListAllEntity> mData = new ArrayList();
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<WatchListAllEntity> items = new ArrayList<WatchListAllEntity>();

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<WatchListAllEntity> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    public void addItem(WatchListAllEntity watchListAllEntity) {

        items.add(watchListAllEntity);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        final int position1 = position;
        if (v == null) {

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.listitempict, null);
        }
        watchListAllEntity = new WatchListAllEntity();
        watchListAllEntity = items.get(position);
        Log.i("position: iteamsLength ", position + ", " + items.size());
        if (watchListAllEntity != null) {

            ImageView itemImage = (ImageView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageviewproduct);

            if (watchListAllEntity.get_thumbnail_image_url1() != null) {

                Drawable image = Utility.ImageOperations(watchListAllEntity.get_thumbnail_image_url1().replace(" ", "%20"),"image.jpg");



                if (image != null) {
                    itemImage.setImageDrawable(image);
                    itemImage.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                } else {

                    itemImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.iconnamecard);
                }

                Log.i("status_ja , status",
                        watchListAllEntity.get_status_ja() + " ,"
                                + watchListAllEntity.getStatus());

                int NewtheStatus = Integer.parseInt(watchListAllEntity
                        .getStatus());
                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.checkboxproduct);
                TextView alreadyOrderText = (TextView) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.alreadyordertext);
                if (NewtheStatus == 1) {
                    alreadyOrderText.setVisibility(4);

                    checkBox.setVisibility(0);
                } else {
                    checkBox.setVisibility(4);
                    alreadyOrderText.setVisibility(0);
                }
                Log.i("Loading ProccardId: ",
                        watchListAllEntity.get_proc_card_id() + "");
                checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                        WatchListAllEntity watchListAllEntity2 = items
                                .get(position1);
                        Log.i("Position: ", position1 + "");

                        if (isChecked) {

                            Constants.orderList.add(watchListAllEntity2
                                    .get_proc_card_id());
                            Log.i("Proc Card Id Add: ",
                                    watchListAllEntity2.get_proc_card_id()
                                            + "");


                        } else {
                            Constants.orderList.remove(watchListAllEntity2
                                    .get_proc_card_id());
                            Log.i("Proc Card Id Remove: ",
                                    watchListAllEntity2.get_proc_card_id()
                                            + "");

                        }

                    }
                });
            }

        }

        return v;
    }
```

Comment: http://www.lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html

Answer (score 0):

Check up your CheckBox element in your newpage.xml file if it contains android:checked="true" statement.